# How to check whether an undetected hard disk is working?

Tags: hard-drive

I would like to know is there any way to check whether an undetected hard disk is working properly.I tried looking with different Live CDs but the hard disk is not detecting.
These are my laptop specifications:

1. Model:HP pavilion G6
2. Hard disk:SATA
3. Processor:AMD A6

More at [HP Pavilion G6](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-g6-1d00-Notebook-PC-series/5186811/model/5220262/document/c03138544/)

Comment: Does the BIOS/UEFI of your machine show the disk? Tried it in another machine?

Comment: @BigChris:Didn't do that.Don't know how to remove the hard disk from laptop.

Comment: @BigChris:Also the disk is not detected in the BIOS of my machine.Is there any way to resolve this.

Comment: Try it in an external case, in another desktop or laptop. First you need to make sure it's not hardware related.

Comment: @SPRBRN:Sure will try that.I'm not aware of how to remove a hard disk from my laptop.Is there any way to remove a hard disk from laptop?

Comment: Google knows the answers for most of the questions - type your model number of the laptop followed by "How to remove hard disk" - I'm sure you will find an answer

Comment: It might be good to note that opening *most* laptops voids their manufacturer's warranties. I'm sure the laptop and/or user manual states this.

Comment: Well that depends on where you live, but opening a laptop to replace a harddisk is totally acceptable in the EU (where I live - no idea where @justin lives), even if the warranty says it is not. The only exception is maybe for replacing batteries that are glued to the motherboard or stuff like that. This case doesn't fall into that category, although it may depend on local law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the manual, open the laptop, and remove the harddisk, then test it in another laptop, and test another harddisk in your laptop.

If you're not sure you can do this, find somebody who does!

See [**HP Pavilion g6-1d63nr Notebook PC User Guides**](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC-series/5186811/model/5220262/manuals)